# English Language Company logo font

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

I am trying to find the font used in this logo:

[image]

I received a png of the logo from the English Language Company, but they do not have a vector version of the font. I am trying to reconstruct the logo for a site.

I have tried WhatTheFont! but got nothing useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the highest resolution you have?

Comment: Yes, sadly, this is the best image they could provide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the font is FS Lola Bold Italic.

[image]

Comment: Ali I think Lola is close but not exact. Look at the u and the y. The source font has more ligatures.

Comment: @Webstarian you are correct. It is close. It may be a custom font. Sadly, the school doesn't have a vector version of their logo, and I have no choice by to try and recreate it as close as possible with the rces  have iIn hand. I would do an image trace, but the logo they provided me is so pixelated that it isn't an easy task. Their web site is http://www.elc.edu.au/en/home and you can see what I mean.

Comment: Hi Ali,  When source graphics aren't available from the client I try a few things before recreating from scratch: ask who the school's publisher is. Who prints their literature, garments and other graphics? Contact those people to see if they have source files. After that I search the web for the logo. A google search for English Language Company brings up their logo as the first result, at 529 pixels wide. This may or may not be used to trace to create a vector version from. I took that image and searched tinyeye, no luck, then put it through google reverse image search which -next comment:

Comment: found several versions, none of them much bigger but some were sharper. This result: http://payload375.cargocollective.com/1/1/32211/9815844/ELC-brand-905px5_905.jpg may be used to trace, clean up and use as vector.