# How to recreate this icon in vector

Tags: vector, icon

I am trying to recreate this icon in a vector format.

[image]

I thought I might find a similar icon on the web which I could simply modify, but have not found anything close enough.

I tried to do a trace in Illustrator but I just got a blob.

Can someone assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the pen tool and the circle with a stroke you can create the globe. For you i have created the globe. And illustrator file attached. download ai [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZempLb0JLQ0p2RjA)

[image]

Comment: You did a much better job than I did. Thank you very much. I am guessing you have a graphics tablet, whereas I am using a mouse...or, you just have a steadier hand.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the answer to this question, would you? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85173/english-language-company-logo-font

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend drawing those blobby shapes with the pen tool. The outer circle should be made just with the ellipse tool. You can expand that and merge everything to create one shape.